# What is the use of band join in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, oracle19c

I am having below table.

```
create table tbl1 ( col1 varchar2(20));
create table tbl2 ( col1 varchar2(20));

Insert into tbl1 (COL1) values ('1');
Insert into tbl1 (COL1) values ('1');
Insert into tbl1 (COL1) values ('1');
Insert into tbl1 (COL1) values ('2');
Insert into tbl1 (COL1) values ('3');
Insert into tbl1 (COL1) values (null);

Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('1');
Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('1');
Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('1');
Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('2');
Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('2');
Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('5');
Insert into tbl2 (COL1) values ('5');
```

i am running below query

```
select a.col1 /*+ use_band(a b) */
from tbl1 a , tbl b
where b.col1 between 4 and 6;
```

and i am getting 12 rows. But even without using **`/*+ use_band(a b) */`** i am getting same 12 rows.
and also we can get this same result by cross join .

so i am having these questions:

A) Why using band join?

B) Is there any performance improvement compared to using inner/outer/left/right joins ?

C) Is there any thing going on in underlying mechanism compared to rest of the joins [inner/outer/left/right/cross]

Link for oracle docs:
[band_join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-568EC26F-199A-4339-BFD9-C4A0B9588937)

Comment: /*+ use_band(a,b) */ is incorrect, no comma needed: /*+ use_band(a b) */
If you had used dbms_xplan.display() you whould have seen:
"Total hints for statement: 1 (E - Syntax error (1))"

Comment: Thanks for telling. But still the result is same

Comment: Of course the result is the same, the objective of query hints is not to change the result set but the way the optimizer fetch the data, and still lot of conditions are take into account to decide if the hint is to be respected or not.

Comment: Noticed that the link conveys the version `19` while `21` is tagged.

Comment: Tag changed to 19C